Inserting the Basename of a file in a href
In my document I have this macro (GraphicIf) to only insert images if they actually exist, and fall-back to an example image otherwise.
Recently though, I wanted to add a href to the basename of the image to that
it could popup the name of the file in a PDF-viewer. I was trying to use this
example
to extract the basename, but combining these two seem to trigger some kind of
infinite recursion:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\filename}[1]{%
 \begingroup
  % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
  \def\textendash{-}%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \edef\filename@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}}%
  \texttt{\filename@base.\filename@ext}%
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\GraphicIf}[2][]{%
\href{\filename{#2}}{%
  \IfFileExists{#2}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}{\includegraphics[#1]{example-image-a}}
}}


\begin{document}

\filename{path/to/file.txt}
\filename{path/to/file_2.txt}
\GraphicIf{Testing.png}

\end{document}


! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<to be read again>
                   T
l.27 \GraphicIf{Testing.png}

Is there someway of actually extracting the filename in this case?

The \href macro expects a simple string as url argument. Instead you provide a macro that does all kinds of processing and also inserts \texttt.
In situations such as this it is often better to call the processing macro outside of the command in which you want to use the result as argument, so the argument you provide is as clean as possible.
In the code below the processed filename is stored using \xdef (expanded global def) into the simple macro \fullfilename which is afterwards used as argument to \href. It should be expanded to get the value at the time of processing (because the unexpanded \filename@base and \@filename@ext may change value later) and it should be global to make it accessible outside of \filename.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\filename}[1]{%
 \begingroup
  % \lstname seems to change hyphens into \textendash
  \def\textendash{-}%
  \filename@parse{#1}%
  \edef\filename@base{\detokenize\expandafter{\filename@base}}%
  \xdef\fullfilename{\filename@base.\filename@ext}%
 \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\GraphicIf}[2][]{%
\filename{#2}%
\href{\fullfilename}{%
  \IfFileExists{#2}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}{\includegraphics[#1]{example-image-a}}
}}


\begin{document}

\GraphicIf{Testing.png}

\end{document}

Result, with the tooltip shown from hovering the mouse over the image:


Not a big fan of relying on macro side-effects, but it works just fine, thanks!

@Xaldew LaTeX is not a 'normal' procedural (or functional) language where functions have return values. It is a macro expansion language, where the code of a macro is more or less directly inserted into the position from which it is called. So your original code would effectively be something like \href{\begingroup\def\textendash{-}\filename@parse{#1}\edef\filename@base ...etc ...}. Therefore a side effect is not really 'outside' in a sense, everything is on the same 'side'.
